# Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Then $\frac{R}{P}$ will have the unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following is the main question I have encountered.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Then $\frac{R}{P}$ is an integral domain.($R$ may not have the unity). If the title can be proved I will be done.

Example: $R$ = $2Z$ and $P$ = $6Z$ , $4+6Z$ is the unity in $\frac{2z}{6z}$

I can prove it when $\frac{R}{P}$ is finite. But I can not see the infinite case.

Can anyone help me by giving a hint.

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052380/prove-that-i-subseteq-r-is-prime-if-and-only-if-r-i-is-an-integral-domain) answer your question?

Comment: no I am finding the unity element of $R/P$..  Everything else is okk.

Comment: @cmi the identity element is $P$.

Comment: sorry unity@Nameless

Comment: @cmi you mean unit? Unit of an element? BUt what does this have to do with the proof?

Comment: no no unity. Not unit.@Nameless

Comment: lin $Z$ 1 is the unity and 0 is the identity.@Nameless

Comment: Don't think it is possible for $R/P$ to be an integral domain if $R$ doesn't have $1.$

Comment: Do u have any counter example? I can not find. and I am quite sure that the statement is correct.@Nameless

Comment: What if R is an integral domain without unity, e.g. R=2Z and P=(0)? Maybe you want to show that *there is* a prime ideal P such that R/P has unity?

Comment: @Nameless  $\mathbb Z\times 2\mathbb Z$ is a ring without identity, and quotienting by $\{0\}\times 2\mathbb Z$ yields an integral domain with identity. So it *is* possible.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $(a + P)(b + P) = 0 + P$ in $R/P$.  Since $(a + P)(b + P) = ab + P$ we get that $ab \in P$.  Now use the definition of a prime ideal.

---

The question used to be: "Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$.  Then $R/P$ is an integral domain."  The OP changed the question, and now asks for a proof that $R/P$ has a unity even if $R$ does not.  Note to OP: if one of the answers addresses the original question then you should accept it and post a new question rather than changing the question.

---

**Edit:** The below is incorrect since the ideal $P$ is not prime as asserted - hat tip @RobertLewis.

<s>To answer the new question, $R/P$ need not have a unity if $R$ does not.  Let $R = C_0(\mathbb{R})$, the ring of continuous functions on the real line which vanish at infinity.  Let $P$ be the prime ideal in $R$ consisting of functions which vanish on the ray $[0, \infty)$.  Consider the map $\phi \colon R \to C_0([0,\infty))$ which sends a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ to its restriction to the ray.  It is clear that this is a ring homomorphism with kernel $P$, and it is surjective by the Tietze extension theorem.  Thus $R/P \cong C_0([0, \infty))$, and this ring does not have a unity: the unity would have to take the value $1$ at every point, but the constant function $1$ does not vanish at infinity.</s>

Comment: I could not understand

Comment: @cmi I have updated my answer to address the new question.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how $P$ is a prime ideal.  Can't I pick $f, g \in R$ such that $fg = 0$ on $[0, \infty)$ but neither $f$ \nor $g$ do?  Can't we take $f$ such that $f(1) = 1$ but $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin (1 - \epsilon, 1 +\epsilon)$ for some positive $\epsilon < 1/4$, and then translate $f$ say, $10$ units to the right to get $g$?

Comment: How $P$ belongs to $R$? perhaps I did not understand the Ring $R$ properly..will $e^{-x}$ belong to $R$?@PaulSiegel

Comment: And I am quite sure that the statement is correct and thank you for your effort but ur earlier answer was wrong as u assumed that $R$ has unity.@PaulSiegel

Comment: Good point @RobertLewis - that kills the argument.

Comment: @PaulSiegel:  Thanks for your response.  I'm still looking into this.  Cheers!

Comment: @cmi: The original argument - that $R/P$ has no zero divisors if $P$ is prime - is true weather or not $R$ has unity.  I'm still not sure about your new claim, that $R/P$ has unity even if $R$ does not - what evidence do you have of this other than the finite case?

Comment: Yes My statement was wrong....Counter example - R=2Z and P=(0)..@PaulSiegel

Answer (score 2):

The statement you want to prove is false. It's essentially equivalent to: does a commutative ring with no nontrivial zero divisors have $1$? $2\Bbb{Z}$ is an easy counterexample.

Why are these equivalent? Well an ideal $P$ is prime iff $R/P$ has no nontrivial zero divisors, and if $R$ is a commutative ring without 1, with no nontrivial zero divisors, the $P=0$ is prime, and $R/P\cong R$ has no 1.

Then it is natural to ask the question, when does a commutative ring with no nontrivial zero divisors have 1?

**Proposition:** A nontrivial commutative ring with no nontrivial zero divisors has a 1 if and only if there are $a,b\ne 0\in R$ such that $ab=b$. Then $a$ is the unit.

*Proof:* If $R$ has 1, then $a=1$ works.

On the other hand, if $ab=b$ with $a\ne 0$, $b\ne 0$, then for any $c\ne 0$, $abc=bc$. Cancelling $b$, since $b\ne 0$, we thus have for all $c\ne 0$, $ac=c$. Thus if it's true for any $b\ne 0$ that $ab=b$, then it's true for *all* $b\ne 0$. Since it's always true that $a0=0$, we thus have that $a$ is the unit of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, integral domains are characterized by the property that

$ab = 0 \Longleftrightarrow a = 0 \; \text{or} \; b = 0; \tag 1$

so if $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$, we look at

$ab + P = (a + P)(b + P) \in R/P; \tag 2$

if

$ab + P = 0 \in R/P, \tag 3$

then

$ab \in P; \tag 4$

thus, since $P$ is a prime ideal,

$a \in P \; \text{or} \; b \in P; \tag 5$

but

$a \in P \Longleftrightarrow a + P = 0 \in R/P, \tag 6$

with a similar assertion binding for $b$.  It follows that either

$a + P = 0 \in R/P \; \text{or} \; b + P = 0 \in R/P, \tag 7$

and thus we have shown that

$ab + P = 0 \in R/P \Longleftrightarrow a + P = 0 \in R/P \; \text{or} \; b + P = 0 \in R/P, \tag 8$

which is precisely the criterion for $R/P$ to be an integral domain.

***Nota Bene:***  I guess I would have to say this is a pretty strong hint!  ***End of Note.***

Comment: That was done by me aswell. But  where did u prove that $R/P$ would have an identity element?

Comment: I didn't; but if $R$ has an identity element $1_R$, it is easy to see that $1_R + P$ is the identity of $R/P$.  So I just took it as known.

Comment: no that is the problem. In my question $R$ may not have unity element

Comment: @cmi:  so a good question is then can $R/P$ have an identity if $R$ doesn't?

Comment: yes that is my question. I can prove it for finite case.

Comment: @cmi:  yes I know about the finite case.  I'm wondering about the infinite case myself . . .

Comment: @cmi:  maybe the issue deserves a question of its own?

Comment: edited..............